# Submit a form with POST action using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I am trying to submit a form using angular1 but when I click submit I can't see the call being made to `/create` in `Network` tab of Chrome Dev tool.

My app.js is:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.loaderHidden = true;

    $scope.csvurls = function() {
        alert("here");
        $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : '/create'
        })
    }
    ....
}]);
```

My form is below:

```
    <form class="form-inline" ng-submit="csvurls()">
      <input type="text" id="inlineFormInput">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

When I click submit I can see the `alert` however, I don't think the call to `/create` is being initiated. I don't see any errors in the log either.

FWIW I am also using `ng-file-upload` in my application.

Comment: You did not include any data with your post command. Also you do not do anything with the resulting promise from `$http` to see if it succeeds or fails and if it fails why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add **$http** as a dependency like this:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$http', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $http, $timeout) {
```